# Split text at single quotes that are not part of a word

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a regex that will extract texts that are surrounded by single quotes into an array. For example, this regex will extract the texts that are between parenthesis:

```
string = "(Well!) thought Alice to herself, (after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!)"
string.scan(/\((?>[^\(\)\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\)/)
# => ["(Well!)", "(after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!)"]
```

I want to do the same with single quotes. I need to ignore single quotes that are preceded and followed by a character in the range of `a-z` or `A-Z` (as in when it is part of a contraction and not used as a quotation).

```
string = "'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"
# => ["'Well!'", "'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"]
```

I tried this:

```
string.scan(/'(?>[^'\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*'/)
# => ["'Well!'", "'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'", "'t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"]
```

Comment: To split out the text between parentheses, can't you simplify  your regex to this: `string.scan /\([^\)]*\)/`? In future, I suggest you pare your code to the essentials and write it in such a way that the reader doesn't have to scroll horizontally.  Here you could have made your point with a much shorter string.

Comment: I assume this will be a problem: "It is ' Buzz' guitar,' I assume"

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, that is one of the edge cases. Any thoughts on how to solve for that?

Comment: I don't see a solution.  It's not just proper nouns ending in 'z' or 's' that's a problem: "Tess' gunna be real mad, cuz' there ain't  no beer in the fridge." or  "Hey, bro', Sheila and Trixie are the cats' meow, n'est-ce pas?".  Note you can't tell if a word is a proper noun by seeing whether it is capitalized, as it could be at the beginning of a sentence. (Tess can confirm.). My advice: hand this project off to the new guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.scan(/(?<![a-zA-Z])'(?:[^']|'[a-zA-Z])*'(?![a-zA-Z])/)
# =>
# [
#    "'Well!'",
#    "'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"
# ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to explain what each part of your regex is doing (for my own education).

Comment: Your regex will fail in the following example: "Let's get Bob's bag." `=> ["'s get Bob'"]`. How can it be changed so that it checks that the first and last single quotes are also not part of a contraction?

Comment: @diasks, I'll explain. `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are negative lookbehind and lookahead [zero-length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), respectively.  They ensure the first (second) `'` is not immediately preceded (followed) by a letter.  `(?:...)*` is a non-capture group which, because of `*` is repeated zero or more times. It must match either (`|`) any character other than (`^` => 'other than') a single quote (`[^']`) or a single quote followed by a letter, and must be bracketed by single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "'Well!' thought Alice to herself, 'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"

p string.scan(/\B'.*?'\B/) #=> ["'Well!'", "'after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they'll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn't say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!'"]
```

Comment: Nice, h. I didn't know about `\B` (match a non-word boundary).  @diasks2, the `?` makes `.*` 'non-greedy', which halts the `.*` match as soon as the following characters in the regex--here `'\B`--is encountered. Without `?`, the default 'greedy' mode would apply, so `.*` would gobble up characters until it reached the last instance of `'\B`, which here is at the end of the string, not what you want.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you this regex

```
'[^']+'
```